# How to create a repo out of only folders?

Tags: git

**Only folders exists in the parent and the subfolders. I've deleted all files using:**

```
find my-path-here -type f -delete
```

example setup:

```
parent-path (this is parent folder for the repo)
  -> subfolder1
  -> subfolder2
  -> subfolder14
  -> subfolder67
```

I tried adding and commiting this setup but git is not adding the subfolders. I've searched the net but didn't see anything useful other than using "git add --all"

Here's my terminal output:

```
parent-path on  master 
➜  rm -rf .git

/home/myuser/parent-path 
➜  git init  
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/myuser/parent-path/.git/

parent-path on  master 
➜  git add .                                                                  

parent-path on  master 
➜  git add --all

parent-path on  master 
➜  git add "subfolder1"

parent-path on  master 
➜  git commit -av -m "initial commit"                                         
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit

parent-path on  master 
➜  git status                        
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

parent-path on  master 
➜  ls -la .gitignore

   Specified path '.gitignore' doesn't exist.

parent-path on  master 
➜
```

Comment: git does not track empty directories.  If there are no links in the directory, it will be ignored.

Comment: GIT does not track directories **at all**. GIT only tracks files. So an empty directoy contains no files, so it's not tracked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a .gitkeep file to each directory you want under version control

Comment: seems I am not restricted to using .gitkeep but any file name will do. Thanks though!